# is freeswitch video transcoding work in 1.6.5?

Tags: webrtc, freeswitch

Is video transcoding VP8-H264 work in freeswitch 1.6.5.?Tried by enabling H264,VP8 in vars.xml codec_pref, but freeswitch sending codecs as same as inbound codecs.

Comment: I think mod_vlc or mod_av handles transcoding. Did you try enabling those?

Comment: Enabled those modules.still video transcoding not working with one leg sipml5(VP8) and other leg bria 3 (H264).bria sending video to freeswitch and sipml5 not sendng any video packets to freeswitch.no video at both legs.

Comment: can you paste the debug logs printed on fscli?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Done the setup successfully by compiling with mod_av module and disabled mod_h26x.

Comment: That's great! Cheers!